# How do I pass in an argument to decorators?

Tags: python, flask

Currently I am trying to use a `login_required` decorator to take in wether the the url endpoint is an API, to determine the return. But currently, it is giving me an error that it is overriding a function. But I have no idea what it is overriding.

Here is my decorators file https://github.com/EndenDragon/DeviantArt-Comic-Reader/blob/d6db44f78f33f23f04eda387f18fd3fea1b2e06c/comicreader/decorators.py#L11

Here is the app function calling the decorator https://github.com/EndenDragon/DeviantArt-Comic-Reader/blob/d6db44f78f33f23f04eda387f18fd3fea1b2e06c/comicreader/blueprints/fetch/fetch.py#L37

Here is the error it produced while running the run.py file

```
$ python run.py 
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "run.py", line 2, in <module>
    from comicreader.app import app
  File "/Users/JeremyZhang/Downloads/DeviantArt-Comic-Reader/comicreader/app.py", line 16, in <module>
    app.register_blueprint(blueprints.fetch.fetch, url_prefix="/fetch")
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/Flask-0.10.1-py2.7.egg/flask/app.py", line 62, in wrapper_func
    return f(self, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/Flask-0.10.1-py2.7.egg/flask/app.py", line 889, in register_blueprint
    blueprint.register(self, options, first_registration)
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/Flask-0.10.1-py2.7.egg/flask/blueprints.py", line 153, in register
    deferred(state)
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/Flask-0.10.1-py2.7.egg/flask/blueprints.py", line 172, in <lambda>
    s.add_url_rule(rule, endpoint, view_func, **options))
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/Flask-0.10.1-py2.7.egg/flask/blueprints.py", line 76, in add_url_rule
    view_func, defaults=defaults, **options)
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/Flask-0.10.1-py2.7.egg/flask/app.py", line 62, in wrapper_func
    return f(self, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/Flask-0.10.1-py2.7.egg/flask/app.py", line 984, in add_url_rule
    'existing endpoint function: %s' % endpoint)
AssertionError: View function mapping is overwriting an existing endpoint function: fetch.decorator
```

What am I doing wrong? I have asked a similar question earlier, but i figured that posting the direct source to the project i am working on should be easier to figure out than to play charades.

Comment: Your posted code never uses your decorator.

Comment: @BrenBarn oops forgot to edit one thing... gimmie a sec. sorry. its supposed to say `print_api_bool` instead of `login_required`. my bad.

Comment: I don't believe this error is related to your decorator, it is related to `@fetch.route("/apipage")`...are you defining this `route` more than one time?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You decorator works alright, here is a Demo:

```
>>> from functools import wraps
>>> 
>>> def p(api=False):
    def decorator(f):
        @wraps(f)
        def decorated_f(*args, **kwargs):
            print(api)
            return f(*args, **kwargs)
        return decorated_f
    return decorator

>>> @p(api=True)
def a():
    return 'api'

>>> a()
True
'api'
```

The error is probably related to something else:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "run.py", line 2, in <module>
    from apiapi.app import app
  -> File "/var/www/python/apiapi.py", line 16, in <module>
    app.register_blueprint(blueprints.fetch.fetch, url_prefix="/fetch")
```

I would suspect that you must be defining this route `@fetch.route("/apipage")` more than one in your code.

After investigation, the issue was that `login_required` according to OP definition has one positional required argument, so a fix for that is to use the decorator this way:

`@login_required()` #for default argument value
`@login_required(api=True)`

Comment: Strange... i commented out this line `app.register_blueprint(blueprints.fetch.fetch, url_prefix="/fetch")` and everything worked. Except that I cannot reach the /fetch url endpoint due to the fact the blueprint isnt registered.

Comment: Do you happen to have `def a():` defined more than once?

Comment: whoops there is a flask implementation of `login_required` decorator. shame on me.

Comment: its giving me the error again, ive instead made a separate question and linked my github code directly on the problem. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38174804/flask-decorators-producing-function-overwrite-error

Comment: Why did u open a new Question?

Comment: blah i thought it would be better to give the github links

Comment: Can you try to add to the [`get_headers`](https://github.com/EndenDragon/DeviantArt-Comic-Reader/blob/d6db44f78f33f23f04eda387f18fd3fea1b2e06c/comicreader/decorators.py#L6) decorator this line: `@wraps(f)` ...just like you did with `login_required` decorator?

Comment: @EndenDragon...Reminding you about decorator basic: *A decorator is a function returning a function* ..`get_headers` is a function returning a function, so you need that [`@wraps`](http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/0.11/patterns/viewdecorators/#login-required-decorator).. if you gonna use it as decorator...

Comment: I am not too sure how to do this... but I am trying to make the variable `headers` available to the function that calls the decorator. http://pastebin.com/J7be2vBy Would you also like to take this to chat?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/116326/discussion-between-iron-fist-and-endendragon).